# corresponding isomorphism real number

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $R = (r,+)$ be the real numbers under addition and let $R^+ = (r^+ , \cdot )$ be the positive real numbers under multiplication. Show that $f : r \rightarrow r^+$ defined by $f(x)= e^x$ ( the natural exponential function ) is an isomorphism from $R$ to $R^+$. What is the corresponding isomorphism from $R^+$ to $R$ ?

This is my solution but I am not sure if it is correct

Notice that for $r, q \in R$,
$$
f(r+q) = e^{r+q}=e^re^q = f(r)*f(q) )$$
and
$$f(0) = e^0 = 1 = identity $$
So $f$ is a group homomorphism.

To show the relationship is one-to-one, first consider injectivity.

Let $r, q \in Q$ such that $f(r) = f(q)$. Then,
$$ e^r = e^q$$

$$ e^r/e^q=1$$

$$ e^{r-q}=1 $$
Thus, $r-1=0$. Hence, $r=q$ and $f$ is injective.

Surjectivity, for any $p \in R^+$, notice that $ln(p)$ is defined, such that
$$f( \ln(p)) = e^{\ln(p)} = p$$
Thus, $f$ is surjective and hence an isomorphism.

The corresponding map from $R^+$ to $R$ is $g(x) = ln(x)$.

Comment: how can I prove it by using exp′(x)=exp(x) and exp(0)=1 ?

Comment: Homomorphism: show that for fixed $y$, the derivative of $\exp(x+y)\exp(-x)$ is zero (product rule), so $\exp(x+y)\exp(-x)$ is a constant, necessarily the constant $\exp(y+0)\exp(-0) = \exp(y)$. Injective: you can show that $\exp$ is monotone increasing, because its derivative $\exp$ is positive at $0$ and never takes the values $0$ $(\exp(x)\exp(-x) = 1)$. Surjective: use the intermediate value theorem, since $\exp(n) = e \cdot ... \cdot e \rightarrow \infty$ and $\exp(-n) = \frac{1}{\exp(n)} \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: i have begun to edit your mathjax, but the changes won't be visible until this is peer-reviewed. basically inline math should be enclosed within dollar signs, and expressions demanding a line to themselves enclosed within double dollar signs.

Comment: thank you tfw cant into math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may gain insight from the following considerations.

suppose $f:R \rightarrow R^+$ is surjective and injective and defined by the functional equation:
$$f(x+y) = f(x)f(y) \\
f(0)=1
$$
then an inverse function $g:R^+ \rightarrow R$ is well-defined in a set-theoretic sense, and must satisfy:
$$
g(xy)=g(f(x')f(y'))=g(f(x'+y'))=x'+y'=g(x)+g(y) \\
g(1)=0
$$

in this context it may also be helpful to note that the (additive Abelian group) automorphisms of $R$ form a multiplicative group isomorphic to $Z_2 \times R^+$. this favour is not returned however, since the (multiplicative Abelian group) automorphisms of $R^+$ are also a multiplicative group isomorphic to $Z_2  \times R^+$